# Linear Search technique

Tags: java, algorithm, linear-search

I am writing a programe that read in file containing a square matrix of N rows by N columns of integers.The first line of the file contains a single value specifying the "size" of N for the rest of the grid. for example if the first line contains "10" then the remainder of the lines form a 10x10 matrix. my program should display the total number of comparisons needed to find (or not find) the given element by using a "brute force" linear technique O(N^2).
Sample c:\temp\input.txt:

10

1   5   8  13  16  18  22  23  28  29

6   9  14  19  20  22  23  27  33  34

11  14  15  20  24  26  27  31  34  39

16  21  23  28  30  34  35  36  39  44

17  25  26  32  36  41  43  47  49  53

19  28  30  35  40  43  44  49  53  56

23  31  33  38  43  48  52  58  60  61

27  34  35  41  44  52  55  59  61  65

29  38  40  44  45  54  60  65  66  67

33  41  46  47  51  59  61  69  70  80

Examples (as a Java App):

java program.class c:\temp\infile.txt 59

58 found in 68 comparisons using a linear search

this is my code

```
   public static int[][] create2DIntMatrixFromFile(String filename) throws Exception {

    int[][] matrix = null;
    String line;
    int size = buffer.read();
    int row=0;
    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] vals = line.trim().split("\\s+");
    if (matrix == null) {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    int size = buffer.read();
    int[][] matrix = new int[100][100];
    matrix = create2DIntMatrixFromFile(args[0]);
    search1(matrix, size,args[1]);
    matrix = new int[size][size];
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
    matrix[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(vals[col]);
     }
    }
    row++;
    }
    return matrix;
    }
    void search1(int [][]matrix,int size,int x)
    {
    int count=0,comp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    { for(int j=0;j<=size;j++)
    if(matrix[i][j]==x) count++;
    comp++;
    }
    System.out.println(count+" found in" + comp + "comparisons using a linear search");
     }
```

the problem is i keep getting syntax error on my main method that search1 method isn't correct and I couldn't fix it. any help I appreciate

Comment: Why construct a matrix? You can filter as you obtain values... No need to store them at all.

Comment: A linear search is O(n), not O(n^2). Ad if your question is about a syntax error, post the error. The first thing I would do is to indent the code. Without indentation, reading it, and thus finding errors, is much harder.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is give well formatted code. From what I was able to understand your problem is probably that you call non static method from static main, so either make search1 static or call it from class constructor(you need to create one).